# Log4Net configuration occasionally append the date multiple times to the file name

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

Often in our production (or production-like) environments, Log4Net is appending the date multiple times to my log files, thus:

```
AppLog.2011.08.26.log
AppLog.2011.08.26.log.2011.08.26.log
AppLog.2011.08.26.log.2011.08.26.log.2011.08.26.log
etc.
```

The files are inconsistently sized and they never reach the 10 MB limit that is set for the maximumFileSize.

Here is my appender setup:

```xml
<appender name="AppLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
            <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs/AppLog[%processid]" />
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="10000KB"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy.MM.dd'.log'"/>
    <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date !! %thread !! %-5level !! %logger !! %property{NDC} !! %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: I am having the same problem today.

Comment: Have you  managed to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You specified `[%processid]` in the value for the log file name,
but in the example you provided for the resulting log file names there is no such value.

With this expander, the resulting name should be something like

```
AppLog[2156].2011.10.07.log
```

If you need the id in the filename, make sure to understand why it is not there. It is possible that you found the origin of the appending problem as well.

Or maybe this is not the appender configuration used to produce these logfiles.